# Trigger Google Optimize experiment or any tag on click event in child or parent component, Application is build on Meteor React Redux

Tags: reactjs, meteor, redux, google-optimize

I'm currently facing an issue with Google Optimize, Application is build on Meteor React Redux, if there is any way to trigger Google Optimize experiment or any tag on click event in child or parent component, experiments are getting triggered on URL basis but, I'm not to add variation for click event at component level.

Suppose there is Cart button on clicking Cart button slider will open in same page, I have to apply Google Optimize experiment for the slider component.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

There are two key steps you need to take, to make this experiment work.

First, you have to set up the experiment triggers. By defeault, experiments start on page load, but this can be changed to so called custom events. Further details are available [here](https://support.google.com/optimize/answer/7008840?hl=en#activate-on-custom-event).

[image]

Second, you need to dispatch this same command, when the relevant event (click on the Cart button in your case) has happened. More precisely, you need to send this event into the datalayer, using the following command.

```
dataLayer.push({'event': 'optimize.activate'});
```

You can customize this event name at the Optimize settings. In this case, the event in the datalayer call has to be aligned.

Comment: Thanks, it's very helpful. 
I'm facing once more issue with GTM,
For single page applications I was wondering if it's possible to remove a custom gtm html tag from the DOM after it has been fired. The idea behind this is to avoid an uncontrollable growing of the DOM through custom scripts.

Comment: A custom html tag gets inserted in the page once per event by default. So such growing is either caused by triggering it multiple times, or by the code within the HTML tag, which could be controlled by you. If the trigger happens multiple times, you can set the tag to run at most once per page. (Advanced settings > Tag firing options). This way, no removal should be necessary. Hope this answers your question.